# How to add LIRC to ir-keytable protocols?

Tags: debian, raspbian

I'm trying to issue a bash command on infrared remote control button presses. The IR receiver device is an usb device included in the Anysee e30 Combo plus DVB-T tuner, which works perfectly, otherwise.

The output of the ir-keytable output:

```
Found /sys/class/rc/rc0/ (/dev/input/event0) with:
Driver dvb_usb_anysee, table rc-anysee
Supported protocols: NEC 
Enabled protocols: 
Name: Anysee
bus: 3, vendor/product: 1c73:861f, version: 0x0100
Repeat delay = 500 ms, repeat period = 125 ms
```

When I run `ir-keytable -t` to test whether the button presses are received, this works and I see scan codes and button labels(KEY_UP etc) showing up. To make a button press fire a bash conmmand, I think my only option is to use LIRC's irexec command.
In installed lirc and configured it, then ran `irw` which is lirc's testing command. No output whatsoever. I checked that lircd is running and that irw can connect to the daemon.

Note that LIRC is not under supported protocols of the ir-keytable command. Does this mean I can't use the hardware for this purpose?

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# modprobe ir-lirc-codec
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# ir-keytable -c -p NEC,LIRC
Old keytable cleared
/sys/class/rc/rc0//protocols: Invalid argument
Couldn't change the IR protocols
```

I saw on a few websites that people do this to add lirc as a protocol. I am not surprised this failed for me though, it would be odd that you could add an unsupported protocol by simply echoing it's name to a file.

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# echo lirc > /sys/class/rc/rc0/protocols
bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument
```

I am using a Raspberry Pi v2 as system (Debian Wheezy)

Answer (score 0):

To enable protocols you must prefix the protocol with a "+" so your statement should be

```
echo +lirc > /sys/class/rc/rc0/protocols
```

see https://www.lirc.org/html/default.html